# Flutter MQTT - Publish to topic1 and Listen to topic2

Tags: flutter, mqtt

I have a Flutter application publishing to 'topic1' and currently listening to 'topic1'.

```
   MQTTManager(
        {required String host,
        required String topic,
        required String identifier,
        required MQTTAppState state})
        :
          _identifier = 'id',
          _host = '48.38.96.88',
          _topic = 'topic1',
          _currentState = state;
```

I want to publish to 'topic1' and then listener to a reply on 'topic2'

Is this possible with [mqtt_client](https://pub.dev/packages/mqtt_client)?

```
 void onConnected() {
      _currentState.setAppConnectionState(MQTTAppConnectionState.connected);
      print('EXAMPLE::Mosquitto client connected....');
      _client!.subscribe(_topic, MqttQos.atLeastOnce);
      _client!.updates!.listen((List<MqttReceivedMessage<MqttMessage?>>? c) {
        // ignore: avoid_as
        final MqttPublishMessage recMess = c![0].payload as MqttPublishMessage;

        // final MqttPublishMessage recMess = c![0].payload;
        final String pt =
            MqttPublishPayload.bytesToStringAsString(recMess.payload.message!);
        _currentState.setReceivedText(pt);
        print(
            'EXAMPLE::Change notification:: topic is <${c[0].topic}>, payload is <-- $pt -->');
        print('');
      });
      print(
          'EXAMPLE::OnConnected client callback - Client connection was sucessful');
    }
  }
```

Comment: If I'm reading the code you've posted right, it isn't going to publish a message until a message is received.

Comment: @hardillb I can see what you are referring to but, but you van publish at any time and receive at any time. I need the publish and receive topics to differ.

Comment: I was more pointing out that the code you've posted does the exact opposite of what you are trying to do. So edit the question to show what you've tried to solve the problem you asked about

Comment: The library https://pub.dev/packages/mqtt_client is written that MqttReceivedMessage and MqttPublishMessage utilize the same topic.

I can not find where to change that the MqttReceivedMessage topic='topic1' and MqttPublishMessage topic ='topic2'

Comment: Like in node-red you can create a node listening to a topic and another publishing to a topic, but somewhere in https://pub.dev/packages/mqtt_client library they assume you will always want to listen and publish to the same topic.

Comment: Scroll further down the example file, there is code to publish to a given topic

Comment: Sorry I can not see the example file you are referring to.

Comment: Flow the link you provided, in the readme there is an example link, and then again flow the example link. But there is a host of examples in the git repo that show publishing to arbitrary topics and subscribing to others https://github.com/shamblett/mqtt_client/blob/master/example/mqtt_server_client.dart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The publish string

```
    void publish(String message) {
      final MqttClientPayloadBuilder builder = MqttClientPayloadBuilder();
      builder.addString(message);
      _client!.publishMessage(_topic1, MqttQos.exactlyOnce, builder.payload!);
    }
```

The subscribe string

```
_client!.subscribe(_topic2, MqttQos.atLeastOnce);
```

You can see the two different topics.

```
  import 'package:mqtt_client/mqtt_client.dart';
  import 'package:flutter_mqtt/mqtt/state/mqtt_app_state.dart';
  import 'package:mqtt_client/mqtt_server_client.dart';

  class MQTTManager {
    // Private instance of client
    final MQTTAppState _currentState;
    MqttServerClient? _client;
    final String _identifier;
    final String _host;
    final String _topic1;
    final String _topic2;

    // Constructor
    // ignore: sort_constructors_first
    MQTTManager(
        {required String host,
        required String topic,
        required String identifier,
        required MQTTAppState state})
        : //_identifier = identifier,
          _identifier = 'id',
          //_host = host,
          _host = '48.38.96.88',
          //_topic = topic,
          _topic1 = 'topic1',
          _topic2 = 'topic2',
          _currentState = state;

    void initializeMQTTClient() {
      _client = MqttServerClient(_host, _identifier);
      //_client = MqttServerClient('48.38.96.88', 'Where');
      _client!.port = 1883;
      _client!.keepAlivePeriod = 20;
      _client!.onDisconnected = onDisconnected;
      _client!.secure = false;
      _client!.logging(on: true);

      /// Add the successful connection callback
      _client!.onConnected = onConnected;
      _client!.onSubscribed = onSubscribed;

      final MqttConnectMessage connMess = MqttConnectMessage()
          .withClientIdentifier(_identifier)
          .withWillTopic(
              'willtopic') // If you set this you must set a will message
          .withWillMessage('My Will message')
          .startClean() // Non persistent session for testing
          .withWillQos(MqttQos.atLeastOnce);
      print('EXAMPLE::Mosquitto client connecting....');
      _client!.connectionMessage = connMess;
    }

    // Connect to the host
    // ignore: avoid_void_async
    void connect() async {
      assert(_client != null);
      try {
        print('EXAMPLE::Mosquitto start client connecting....');
        _currentState.setAppConnectionState(MQTTAppConnectionState.connecting);
        await _client!.connect();
      } on Exception catch (e) {
        print('EXAMPLE::client exception - $e');
        disconnect();
      }
    }

    void disconnect() {
      print('Disconnected');
      _client!.disconnect();
    }

    void publish(String message) {
      final MqttClientPayloadBuilder builder = MqttClientPayloadBuilder();
      builder.addString(message);
      _client!.publishMessage(_topic1, MqttQos.exactlyOnce, builder.payload!);
    }

    /// The subscribed callback
    void onSubscribed(String topic) {
      print('EXAMPLE::Subscription confirmed for topic $topic');
    }

    /// The unsolicited disconnect callback
    void onDisconnected() {
      print('EXAMPLE::OnDisconnected client callback - Client disconnection');
      if (_client!.connectionStatus!.returnCode ==
          MqttConnectReturnCode.noneSpecified) {
        print('EXAMPLE::OnDisconnected callback is solicited, this is correct');
      }
      _currentState.setAppConnectionState(MQTTAppConnectionState.disconnected);
    }

    /// The successful connect callback
    void onConnected() {
      _currentState.setAppConnectionState(MQTTAppConnectionState.connected);
      print('EXAMPLE::Mosquitto client connected....');
      _client!.subscribe(_topic2, MqttQos.atLeastOnce);
      _client!.updates!.listen((List<MqttReceivedMessage<MqttMessage?>>? c) {
        // ignore: avoid_as
        final MqttPublishMessage recMess = c![0].payload as MqttPublishMessage;

        // final MqttPublishMessage recMess = c![0].payload;
        final String pt =
            MqttPublishPayload.bytesToStringAsString(recMess.payload.message!);
        _currentState.setReceivedText(pt);
        print(
            'EXAMPLE::Change notification:: topic is <${c[0].topic}>, payload is <-- $pt -->');
        print('');
      });
      print(
          'EXAMPLE::OnConnected client callback - Client connection was sucessful');
    }
  }
```